# are there any hosting servers enables mutable ip addresses?

Tags: php, apache

i want to run a php server side code, on apache. are there any servers suppliers which enables your code opens ports using diffrent ips?

for example for 5 minutes my code will use this ip:

```
213.168.0.17
```

and after that it will switch the ip and will use this one (e.g):

```
213.198.0.10
```

and then after 5 minutes to switch for pseudo random ip again and agian.

i don't want my code to use the same ip all the time.

thanks

Comment: Highly unlikely. There's few enough available IPv4 addresses out there to waste them on a service like this. As well, most hosting services don't have multiple IP blocks that'd allow the kind of variety you seem to require. They'll have a single contiguous block.

Comment: Why on earth would you want that? How would anybody ever be able to visit your site?

Comment: This question made me think of Untraceable.

Comment: lol, i'll explain. i want that for each visit in my site, to make one query to some other web site which limits the number of queries the same ip can do in a short timing, i think if there any solution as i asked for that would be great isn't it ?

Comment: Then you should hit the other site via a cronjob and cache the result locally.

Comment: I think the appropriate thing to do would be to buy a license to access this site legitimately.

Comment: There are some hosts that let you use several different IPs (there are legitimate uses) for the same server, but what your talking about really requires a proxying service.

Comment: if there any host service which aggregates all the request from is costumers and then fork them, would do the work as well, style of proxy server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering this with the assumption that you will use this information in good faith.

If you are accessing a resource on another website, I suggest that you use cURL and harness its proxy option. You may check out the CURLOPT_PROXY option ([curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)) for this.

All you have to do is gather a list of 'working' proxy servers, put them in an array or a database and pick a certain IP to use for the certain time range.

You might also find this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211887/how-to-use-curl-via-a-proxy) useful.

Answer (score 1):

When using cURL, you can use `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, '1.2.3.4')` to specify the outgoing IP address. However, there's no way to do this for all outgoing requests from a server - you really have to specify this for each cURL request, and `file_get_contents` won't give you this kind of control.