# simple_html_dom.php parser not working

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, dom

I downloaded the simple_html_dom.php file and uploaded it to my web server and I immediately tested it with a simple script, but it won't work, or at least I suppose it doesn't since it doesn't output anything.

Here's the script:

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');

// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html('http://davidwalsh.name/');

// Find all "A" tags and print their HREFs
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) {
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
}
?>
```

I got the script from this site http://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications and the same was presented on other sites so I don't understand why it won't output anything.

My guess is that the script isn't able to retrieve any data from the other website, something like the problem I came across here: [Retrieving cross-domain data php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281904/retrieving-cross-domain-data-php).

If it were like so, could there be any way to avoid the problem?

In BIno Carlos' answer to the question I linked before he stated "it's not really a cross domain problem because you are loading the data from the server not the browser", so could there be for example a way to load the data from the browser?

So, as suggested by user868766 in his answer, i tried the two ini_set methods which didn't report any errors, so it would seem like the script works apparently just fine. When I tried the print_r() method on $html it outputted the below:

```
simple_html_dom Object ( [root] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 5 [tag] => root [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( ) [nodes] => Array ( ) [parent] => [_] => Array ( [0] => -1 [1] => 1 ) [dom:simple_html_dom_node:private] => simple_html_dom Object *RECURSION* ) [nodes] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 5 [tag] => root [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( ) [nodes] => Array ( ) [parent] => [_] => Array ( [0] => -1 [1] => 1 ) [dom:simple_html_dom_node:private] => simple_html_dom Object *RECURSION* ) ) [callback] => [lowercase] => 1 [pos:protected] => 0 [char:protected] => [size:protected] => 0 [cursor:protected] => 1 [parent:protected] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 5 [tag] => root [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( ) [nodes] => Array ( ) [parent] => [_] => Array ( [0] => -1 [1] => 1 ) [dom:simple_html_dom_node:private] => simple_html_dom Object *RECURSION* ) [token_blank:protected] => [token_equal:protected] => =/> [token_slash:protected] => /> [token_attr:protected] => > [self_closing_tags:protected] => Array ( [img] => 1 [br] => 1 [input] => 1 [meta] => 1 [link] => 1 [hr] => 1 [base] => 1 [embed] => 1 [spacer] => 1 ) [block_tags:protected] => Array ( [root] => 1 [body] => 1 [form] => 1 [div] => 1 [span] => 1 [table] => 1 ) [optional_closing_tags:protected] => Array ( [tr] => Array ( [tr] => 1 [td] => 1 [th] => 1 ) [th] => Array ( [th] => 1 ) [td] => Array ( [td] => 1 ) [li] => Array ( [li] => 1 ) [dt] => Array ( [dt] => 1 [dd] => 1 ) [dd] => Array ( [dd] => 1 [dt] => 1 ) [dl] => Array ( [dd] => 1 [dt] => 1 ) [p] => Array ( [p] => 1 ) [nobr] => Array ( [nobr] => 1 ) ) [doc:protected] => [noise:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

Comment: Have you done **ANY** basic debugging, e.g. dump out the value of $html to make sure you received something?

Comment: Also, why not use the inbuilt DOMDocument functionality? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-xmldomphp/

Comment: It is imprecise, but for won't work I meant won't output anything. It's like it could recognize the functions and all but it wasn't able to grab any content from the other site.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is working fine for me.

Think you can try these, put below lines on top of script :

```
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Also check print_r of $html

```
    print_r($html);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, the first two didn't output anything, seems the script would work fine. Now I'll update the print_r() method's output.