# How do I access a php file from another domain

Tags: php, html, dns, request

Say I got 3 websites. Every time I do an action on site (1), I need to access file.php from (2) and (3) with the parameter of the site the action has been done ( (1) in this case ), so, for this example, I need to access:

```
(2).com/file.php?site=1 
(3).com/file.php?site=1
```

The same applies if the action is done from the website (2) and (3).

What is the best way to approach this? ( I don't want to manually access the file from my browser every time said action happens on the website (x) )

I tried doing a simple:

```
<form method="get" action="(2).com/file.php?site=1"> </form>
<form method="get" action="(3).com/file.php?site=1"> </form>
```

It doesn't work.

I tried doing some kind of ajax/XMLHttpRequest and also tried using the "file" PHP function.

So, my question is, how do I approach this? What is the best way to "virtually" open a browser, and load a PHP file?

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? Why is XMLHttpRequest not working for you? Did you try using `curl`?

Comment: I just want to access it the same way I'd access it via a browser ( I don't want a POST form, just a normal GET ). All domains are on the same server, but they don't really have access one to another. (all are different domains).

I have not tried `curl`

Answer (score 1):

Use `curl` via a proxy for cross-domain queries.

Here's an example taken from another SO question ( [How to use CURL via a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211887/how-to-use-curl-via-a-proxy) )

```
<?php


$url = 'http://www.php.net';
$proxy = '10.10.10.101:8080';
//$proxyauth = 'user:password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

Comment: Why would OP need a proxy for that?

Comment: ^ 

Also, could I be able to send parameters? Like:

    `$url = 'http://www.php.net/index.php?someParam=1&hello=true'`

Comment: @kingkero is correct, a proxy is not needed for this -- my apologies as I misread the question, but curl is still a good use for this.

Comment: @PirvuMihai-Cristian yes, you can pass query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry because I haven't used the Search function enough :(

I would've tried curl, but the code Prefix used didn't work on my site and when I tried it locally, it said that `curl` was not installed, so I proceeded to try the next thing that was in sight. I ended up using this code, from another SO thread: [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

```
$url = 'http://server.com/path';
$data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result)
```

Comment: Cheers, glad you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP files from other domains normally (to handle requests, echo results etc.), but you need to add the following headers to the PHP files on your other domains. This is needed for ajax or xmlhttprequests.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```