# php - how to use curl with proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I need to access a website from php with curl, but I must use a proxy.

Is there a simple way to set curl to use a proxy?

If there is no simple way, what other options are available?

Please supply a code example

Answer (score 1):

Did you searched already on stackoverflow?
You might check this answer [How to use CURL via a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211887/how-to-use-curl-via-a-proxy)

Or doesn't answer this your question?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.foo.bar');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'proxy:8080');    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'domain\user:password');    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://myreferer.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla...');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```