# curl php - CURLOPT_PROXY

Tags: php, curl, proxy

```
   $options = array( 
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // to return web page
   CURLOPT_HEADER         => false, // to return headers in addition to content
   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // to follow redirects
   CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",   // to handle all encodings
   CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true, // to set referer on redirect
   CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,  // set a timeout on connect
   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 5,  // set a timeout on response
   CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 5,   // to stop after 10 redirects
   CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT    => true, // no header out
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,// to disable SSL Cert checks
   CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE   => true,  
   CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
   COOKIESESSION          => true,
    );

    $handle = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $handle, $options );
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, '69.7.113.4');
    $raw_content = curl_exec( $handle );
    curl_close( $handle );
```

As soon as i use curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, '69.7.113.4');
i cant get it working, is there a windows setting i need to change?

if i just comment the line curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, '69.7.113.4'); i get a response.

Response

```
Array ( [url] => [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 5.008 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 [errno] => 28 [errmsg] => Connection timed out after 5008 milliseconds [headers] => [content] => )
```

Comment: Try to adde the port, e.g. '69.7.113.4:80'. Is any authentication needed for the proxy?

Comment: Addition: Does curl_error say anything?

Comment: Add the port number. Make sure the proxy doesn't need authentication. If it's a SOCKS proxy, you'll need to set proper `CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE`.

Comment: i am trying it with www.google.com and it should not need any authentication.

Comment: @Hans Gerber - Even if i add port, doesnt works. Also i get  error 28 which is a connection timeout.

Comment: Well timeout looks like there is a problem with the proxy. I tried to use it in my browser and it seems to endlessly redirect to '[hostname]/cgi-bin/restart/'

Comment: Well .. so a connection is possible, but you need to know the proper port.

Comment: ok let me try to figure out a port..but the port ranges is huge...65535

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use CURL via a proxy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211887/how-to-use-curl-via-a-proxy)