# proxy server configuration in hybridauth

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, proxy, hybridauth

am working on a PHP site(CodeIgniter) which uses HybridAuth to support social login.now I must use proxy server to send requests to providers(facebook,google..).
where should i configure proxy server details in hybridauth?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure Hybridauth use CURL sending request out. It should be achieveable
 by setup proxy with CURL before calling the hybridauth class. [see this post to see how to setup proxy with CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211887/how-to-use-curl-via-a-proxy)