# Problem with getting source code of a web page using PHP curl

Tags: php, curl

I have absolutely no problem in getting source code of the webpage in my local server with this:

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://opac.nlai.ir');
```

And I was also okay on my host using code below until just a few days ago:

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://opac.nlai.ir');  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);  
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

But today I figured out that now the site is using ssl and it is not working with http anymore and force redirect to https. So I did some search & found this as a fix:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($curl CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

The code above works just fine for sites like e.g. "https://google.com" (and any other https sites that I've tried! )
But not for that specific website ("https://opac.nlai.ir")
In that case, page takes about a minute to load (!) and finally with var_dump($result) , I get "bool(false)"
I don't know how that website can be different from other websites and I really want to know what cause the problem.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: What debugging have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl/14436877

Comment: @Hesam Looks like they are have problems in their server.  It is not your fault.  I have tried to open their page from two different IPs via browsers and both got timeout error after around 2 minutes.

Comment: @masterguru Yes it seems the server is only responding to specific IP location, so I found the problem! My host should be located in that location... Or is there any PHP curl related solution for that?

Comment: Surely using a proxy IP located in the area allowed to browse the site you can still use cUrl. If you found any check this post: [How to use cUrl via a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211887/how-to-use-curl-via-a-proxy)

Comment: @masterguru Thanks a lot! It is working now via proxy

Comment: @Hesam: Great. Nice to know you fixed it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filling this answer for the records.

---

As said in question comments, the website where you were trying to get its source code **was blocking your requests due your server location area** (that executed the requests). It seems it **only responds to specific IP location**.

The **solution** verified by @Hesam has been to **use cUrl via a proxy IP located in allowed location area**, and he found one at least running well.

He followed the instructions found in this other SO post:
[How ot use cUrl via a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211887/how-to-use-curl-via-a-proxy)