# how to curl use proxy in codeigniter4?

Tags: php, curl, codeigniter-4

how to curl use proxy in codeigniter4?

I have read on https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/curlrequest.html?highlight=curl but can't find a solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use CURL via a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211887/how-to-use-curl-via-a-proxy)

Comment: I believe the `CURLRequest` class is written such that you can only adjust the options that are exposed to you in the documentation. If you need further functionality, you should probably use the `CURL` library built into PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php